# How do I pass values to a `sqlQuery "…WHERE x IN ?"` in IHP?

Tags: sql, postgresql, haskell, ihp

I've tried

```
users :: [Users] <- sqlQuery "SELECT * FROM users u … WHERE u.id IN ?" (userIds :: [Id User])
```

and `(Only userIds)` and `(In userIds)` but no success. I can't find any examples in the [docs](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/api-docs/IHP-Fetch.html#t:In).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's using postgres-simple under the hood, https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.6.5/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#g:6 gave the answer:

```
users :: [Users] <- sqlQuery "SELECT * FROM users u … WHERE u.id IN ?" (Only (In userIds))
```